# How to use jquery-validate localization

Tags: jquery, localization, jquery-validate

Is there a way to dynamically (i.e. from JS code) set/change the language of error messages, using the existing translations available in the repo?

**Non-solution #1**: Loading a localization script (`<script type="text/javascript" src="localization/messages_XX.js">`) won't work because it cannot be changed on the client-side.

**Non-solution #2**: Setting custom messages with `setDefaults` requires me to come up with my own strings instead of reusing the existing ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jQuery `$.extend()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) to dynamically replace all messages at any time.

```
$.extend($.validator.messages, {....});
```

Example:

```
var en = {
        required: "This field is required.",
        ....
    },
    ca = {
        required: "Aquest camp és obligatori.",
        ....
    },
    de = {
        required: "Dieses Feld ist ein Pflichtfeld.",
        ....
    };

$('#language').on('change', function() {
    $.extend($.validator.messages, eval($(this).val()));
});

$('#myform').validate({ ....
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lwvoo39u/**

Localization:  [github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/tree/master/src/localization](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/tree/master/src/localization)

Comment: I marked this answer as accepted even though it's not exactly what I was looking for. To clearify: I'd like to use the localization files from the repo as-is (directly benefiting from future changes/improvements to those files); with your solution (or the similar 'setDefaults' solution), I have to manually copy the localization data from messages_de.js, messages_et.js etc. into my own code, requiring me to manually manage that data. I was hoping for a dynamic mechanism similar to e.g. Datatables (datatables.net) which provides an API to dynamically load the lib's own localization data.

Comment: @dr_barto, there is practically nothing contained in the localizations that should change over time, so once the messages are copied into your own file, there is no code to "maintain".